# Angular2 Http - No Errors, No Connection

Tags: angular

I am having a really hard time determining what is wrong with my code. I am trying to create a service class to connect to my separate database application which exposes an open (unsecure) REST API.

If I connect to the address in my browser I can correctly see the results, and a connection is logged on my server. However when I try to connect via my Angular2 service class I get no errors and no connection attempt on my server.

I have been rewriting the below over and over again, reading the docs and cannot figure it out! I am using 2.0.1.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  private loggedIn = false;
  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(user:any): Observable<any[]> {

    var x = this.http.get(this.loginUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);

    console.log(x);
    console.log("Sent?");

    return null;
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
}
```

In my console I see the results of console(x) and console('sent?') so I know the code is being executed.

Comment: Have you injected `HttpModule` in app.module or main.module file???

Comment: You can use  `return x;` instead of `return null;` and in component you can subscribe to login method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `subscribe()` or `toPromise()` an `Observable` isn't doing anything because they are lazy

```
var x = this.http.get(this.loginUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

This way it makes the request

```
var x = this.http.get(this.loginUrl)
                .subscribe(this.extractData, this.handleError);
```

You need to be cautious about using `thin.` in `extractData` and `handleError`.
It's usually better to always use arrow functions

```
var x = this.http.get(this.loginUrl)
                .subscribe(data => this.extractData(data), 
                           err => this.handleError(err));
```

Comment: Ah awesome thanks! Will accept as soon as I am allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to subscribe to the http.get call.

You need to type:

```
 http.get(...).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

to make the actual call.

Observables are cold, that means without subscribing nothing happens.